# No results with pymongo's aggregation syntax

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm querying a db in mongo using the aggregation framework as follows:

```
db.items.aggregate({$group: {_id: "$seller_id", totalSold : { $sum: "$sold_quantity"} }},
 { $match: {totalSold: {$gte: 100}}}, {$sort:{totalSold: -1}}, {$limit:10})
```

The above command runs ok in mongo shell, but it returns no results when ran in python with pymongo's library as follows:

```
pipeline = [{"$group": {"_id": "$seller_id", "totalSold" : { "$sum": "$sold_quantity"} }},
 { "$match": {"totalSold": {"$gte": 500}}}, {"$sort": SON([("totalSold", -1)])}, {"$limit":10}]
    items_it = self.items.aggregate(pipeline)
```

I've been reading the pymongo's documentation and some threads from this site but I couldn't find a way to modify the syntax in order to get the results.

Comment: What is the version of PyMongo you are using?

Comment: I'm using pymongo 2.6.1 version.

Comment: The Python syntax looks right to me. What is "self.items"? Is it definitely the same collection as "db.items" in the shell?

Answer (score 0):

In second example your variable `pipeline` is a list. Try it:

```
items_it = self.items.aggregate(pipeline[0])
```

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting the same results: [u'ok', u'result']

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pipeline = [{"$group": {"_id": "$seller_id", "totalSold" : { "$sum": "$sold_quantity"} }},
 { "$match": {"totalSold": {"$gte": 500}}}, {"$sort": {"totalSold": -1}}, {"$limit":10}]
    items_it = self.items.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with pymongo 2.5.2 connecting to a mongo 3.0.2 database. I believe it's a bug. Updating to the newest version of pymongo (3.0.2+git) resolved the problem.